# AWS S3 Sync renamed files

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Is there a way to perform an exact mirror of local vs S3, i.e. If I rename a file locally, is there a way to apply that to S3 as well?

Comment: Event based execution of `aws s3 sync` or Use of [AWS File Share & File Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/aws-storage-gateway-in-2019/) can be an option or Using [s3fs-fuse](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) are few options.

Answer (score 0):

If two locations are synchronized and then a local file is renamed, then next time that `aws s3 sync` is run, the file will be treated as a new file and it will be copied to the destination.

The original file in the destination will remain untouched. However, if the `--delete` option is used, then the original file in the destination will be deleted.

The `sync` command does not rename remote files. It either copies them or deletes them.

There are some utilities that can mount Amazon S3 as a virtual disk, such that changes are updates on Amazon S3. This is great for copying data, but is not recommended for production usage at high volumes.